# How to save an calendar event from my app?

Tags: android, events, calendar

I have this following code for creating an event.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");   
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());  
intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);  
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");  
startActivity(intent);
```

This just re directs me to the create event activity in the default calendar app with the values I have provided.

I just want to know, is there any way I could save this event with the values I have provided without getting redirected to the create event activity?
That is, I want to create this event and save this event from my app, instead of making my user to move to another app.

Is this possible?